# Showing bootstrap modal on any website page using chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a chrome extension where my requirement is to show a bootstrap form overlaying website in the current tab. But it's behavior is quite buggy.Sometimes it works but sometimes it's unable to click.

I am injecting bootstrap library and Modal popup code using Background.js page of chrome extension. So, as soon as the modal.js (Modal popup) is injected it will show the popup.

As per the use case I want to show the popup when user clicks a button on popup.html, which is shown when user clicks browser action button.

This is the code to inject libraries and modal.js

```
chrome.tabs.insertCSS(null, {
        file: "css/bootstrap.min.css"
        }, function() {
            if (chrome.extension.lastError) {
                chrome.extension.lastError.message;
                alert("We are sorry, but chrome reserved pages (new tab, extensions, etc) and chrome web store are not supported. Please try another page.")
            }

             chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                file: "js/lib/jquery.js"
            });

            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                file: "js/lib/bootstrap.min.js"
            });

            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                file: "js/modal.js"
            });
        });
```

One more info, this issue comes up only when I execute on any other website. This popup shows fine when run on chrome new tab page.

Could anybody tell me steps I am doing wrong or any better way to do this?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Makyen. I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In manifest.json

```
"permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "css": ["css/bootstrap.min.css", "css/estilo.css"],
      "js": ["js/jquery.min.js", "js/bootstrap.min.js", "js/script.js", "js/funcion.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
```

In script.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(){ 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'js/funcion.js' });    
    window.close();
  });
});
```

In funcion.js

```
$("#modal1").modal("show");
```

modal1 is a modal build in a var that append to the body of the page